# Bootstrap: Image will not right align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on this on Codepen as I'm new to Bootstrap & its a good site to practice on for a novice like myself.

I'm trying to right align an image in the bottom right hand corner but am failing. From my own research on this I'm not sure if the "pull-right" can/should(?) be used. What puzzles me is that the code for the image left aligned works fine, so what am I missing from the code for the right align image?

```
 <body>
<!--
This section sets the left top image
-->
<div class = "media">
   <div class = "media-left">
    <img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/6/5191/7094248657_1cde1542b4_z.jpg" class="media-object" style="width:250px">
  </div>

  <!--
This section contains the heading & any additional text added
-->
  <div class = "media-body">
    <div class = "heading">
      <h2 class = "media-heading">SWIMMING</h2></div>
    <p>A great way to unwind.</p>
  </div>

  <!--
This section contains the top right image
-->
  <div class = "media-right">
    <img src="//c1.staticflickr.com/6/5560/31273130652_169a8d4eae_k.jpg" class="media-object" style="width:250px">
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

 <!--
This section contains the centre image
-->
  <div class = "bikini">
  <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12 bikini">

      <img class = "center-block img-responsive" src="http://c1.staticflickr.com/6/5090/5283880278_506cd08780_b.jpg" style="width:300px"> </div>
      </div>   
</div>
  </div>
<br>
  <br>

  <!--
This section contains the lower left image
-->
  <div class = "media">
   <div class = "media-left">
    <img class="media-object pull-left" src="//c1.staticflickr.com/7/6224/6345332948_ccd0793d3c_b.jpg" class="media-object" style="width:250px">
  </div>
  </div>

  <!--
This section contains the lower right image
-->
 <div class = "media">
   <div class = "media-right">
     <img class = "media-object pull-right" src="//c1.staticflickr.com/4/3152/2349904544_b8534c5b4e_b.jpg" class="media-object" style="width:250px">

  </div>
  </div> 


      </body>
```

Comment: Can you link the CodePen?

Comment: Please post your CSS as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all for the future, please format your code! It makes it more readable and we could faster help you to solve the issue.

And now to your problem. The first one was that you two div's were wrong placed. If that was solved `pull-right` works like a charm (if bootstrap.css is included), but to place in every single row the image I used the bootstrap class `col-xs-12`. (read more about the grid-system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid))

working solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkurzweil/jcpxkdv3/8/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tryed it but the layout came out jumbled and not the way I wanted it to be. The issue is my lack of clear understanding of the Bootstrap grid system. I'm learning but I need to practise a lot more putting the theory into coding practise. I did change the end of the Codepen to something more manageable.Its not perfect but as a novice I'm happy with it. The finished page is here https://codepen.io/Horseman/pen/BpxNxR

Comment: @Achill looks great, only a suggestion from my side. Try to make the window size smaller and handle with the grid system your first row (image, text, image). The right image shouldn't disappear out of the window...

Comment: Thks for that. With hindsight, having to change the end of the page to thumbnails gave me a valuable clue as to what I was doing wrong. Simply put I need to experiment with size in the Bootstrap grid. Changing <div class = "col-xs-4" "col-md-2 thumbnail"> to <div class = "col-xs-3" "col-md-2 thumbnail"> meant the 4 thumbnails fit on the one line. Just have to remember that its a 12 column in my next project.